# Form_for submit button not routing to create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form_for and I want when text is entered in the text area ad the submit button is clicked the create action on my controller is called, but instead it does noting but stay on the same page and the url on the browser changes from `localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:3000/?utf8=✓&authenticity_token=6qNPP4KXB0B1G1X%2BG4UIakH5nhso1BJRlRJVukjL0jI%3D&speech%5Bwording%5D=&commit=Save+Speech` - I don't understand what this url is doing? Even when I delete my create method in the controller I should be getting an error stating "The action create could not be found for SpeechsController" but instead i just get that long url?

controller:

```
    class SpeechsController < ApplicationController

def create
end

end
```

form:

```
  <form class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="input-group" style="width:340px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;">
        <%= form_for :speech, url: speechs_path do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_area :wording, :class => "form-control", :style => "height:250px;width:540px;margin:0 auto;" %><br></br>
        <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
    <% end %>
  </form>
```

routes:

```
  esources :speechs, except: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy] do 
  collection do 
    get 'create'
  end 
end
  root "welcome#home"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should **not** have to add the `collection do get 'create'` to your `routes.rb` because `create` is one of the default Rails route actions.

Second, if the `create` is an HTTP POST request, you should **not** specifying it with `get`. That is why you got that long url.

Inside your controller, add the `.create` method inside your `create` action. For example:

```
def create
  @speech = Speech.create(params[:speech])
end
```

Now the form in your view should be something like this:

```
<%= form_for Speech.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :wording %>
  <%= f.submit  %>
<% end %>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This should be the ideal way

**Controller**

```
class SpeechsController < ApplicationController

def new
 @speech = Speech.new
end

def create
  #Your Create logic here
end

end
```

**View** Notice the `@speech` here in view

```
#app/views/speeches/new.html.erb
<form class="col-lg-12">
    <div >
        <%= form_for @speech do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_area :wording, :class => "form-control" %>
        <%= f.submit  %>
    <% end %>
  </form>
```

**Routes**

```
resources :speeches, only: [:new,:create]
```